# Creating a new project Visual Studio 2015 and PGI Visual Fortran

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, pgi, pgi-visual-fortran

I have installed Visual Studio and PGI Visual Fortran 18.5  on my machine. Installation went smoothly, but when I try to create a new project on Visual Studio I get the following error:

[image]

```
"C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\...\PVF...pvfproj cannot be opened becasue its project type (.pvfproj) is not supported by this version of the application. To open it, please use a version that supports this type of project."
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: Please include the text message as text in the question so that it can be searched by others. Consider using the [tag:fortran] tag even when the question is not about the language.

Comment: This seems to indicate that something didn't get installed correctly.  Can you try opening one of the included sample PVF projects?